# Are these two separation results equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a real topological vector space, and let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty, disjoint, convex subsets of $X$.

**S1.** If $A$ is *open*, then there exists $c \in \mathbb R$ and a nonzero, linear, continuous, real-valued function $f$ on $X$ such that $f(a) \leq c$ for all $a \in A$ and $f(b) \geq c$ for all $b \in B$.

**S2.** If $A$ has *nonempty interior*, then there exists $c \in \mathbb R$ and a nonzero, linear, continuous, real-valued function $f$ on $X$ such that $f(a) \leq c$ for all $a \in A$ and $f(b) \geq c$ for all $b \in B$.

Both S1 and S2 are true, but I am wondering...

**Question.** Is there an easy way to see that S1 implies S2?

If S1 holds, and $A$ has nonempty interior, then we can find a nonzero, linear, continuous function $f$ that separates $B$ from int$A$. But I don't see that $f$ necessarily separates $B$ from all of $A$, nor do I see how to modify $f$ to make this the case. Any hints are appreciated.

---

**Added.** Does the following argument work?

As above, if S1 holds, then there is a nonzero, linear, continuous $f$ that separates $B$ and int$A$. Since $f$ is continuous, it also separates $B$ from cl(int$A$), the closure of int$A$. But in a topological vector space, cl(int$C$) = cl$C$ for any convex $C$, and so $f$ separates $B$ from cl$A$. It follows that $f$ separates $B$ and $A$.

Comment: An open set is equal to its interior.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, and that shows that S2 implies S1...

Comment: The strict separation from S1 becomes by passing to limit the separation you need in S2. Because A in S2 is a solid it is included in the closure of its interior.

Comment: @NeutralElement This sounds like the argument that I gave under "Added". Is that correct?

Comment: I think your argument is correct

Comment: Great, thanks. If you had a somewhat different argument in mind and want to write it up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.